# Updating store is not consistent on checkbox event

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

On check item in checkbox field, store update is not consistent. If i check **All** items store should get update. i have more than 15 items in store, its not updating some items in store. Same behavior in both device and browser

```
onCheckItem:function(check){
            var i=0;
            var record = this.getRecord();
            var customStore=Ext.getStore('customStore');
            var customStoreVal=customStore.findRecord('title',record.get('title'));
            if(record.get('title')==='All' && record.get('checkeditems')===false || record.get('checkeditems')==='false' ){
                    customStore.each(function(updateRecord){
                    updateRecord.set('checkeditems', true);
                 });

            }
    },
```

Comment: What you mean is that "updateRecord.set('checkeditems', true);" does not update your store ? Or you don't see your checkbox checked ?

Comment: @BenoitCuvelier Thanks for your response. i solved this using check listener.. instead of updaterecord. and its working fine. Thanks.